# Referenciar partes de um programa externo C#

Tags: c#, input, textbox

Preciso referenciar o *input* (`textBox`) de login de um programa que está rodando no meu PC. Vocês saberiam me indicar o caminho para fazer isso?

Preciso capturar o login digitado no programa externo pelo meu programa no Visual Studio.

Comment: Você tem o código fonte desse programa?

Comment: do programa que eu quero referenciar o input não, seria somente com o código?

Comment: Não necessariamente. Tem algumas maneiras de fazer isso, mais creio que tentar capturar assim não é uma boa ideia. Um dúvida: por que você precisa fazer isso? Não estás tentando "roubar" nenhum login e senha, né?

Comment: Nao, nao e so o input que preciso, preciso referenciar labels e outros componentes tbm..